# TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy error at integration-test with maven-failsafe-plugin spring-boot 1.4

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm getting **ArrayStoreException**: **TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy** when running integration-test with maven-failsafe-plugin and spring-boot 1.4.

You can see this error if you run [joinfaces-example](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces-example/tree/TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy) with

**mvn -Pattach-integration-test clean install**

I realized that the error does not occur if I change spring-boot-maven-plugin to run at **pre-integration-test** phase instead of **package** one.

More, this error started when I upgraded spring boot to 1.4. No error occurs if I change jsf-spring-boot-parent version to 2.0.0 which uses spring boot 1.3 version.

Comment: I have the exact same error after upgrading from SpringBoot 1.3 to SpringBoot 1.4.0, I get the error when running failsafe integration tests using `mvn install failsafe:integration-test`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I actually found the answer in [Spring Boot 1.4 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#integration-tests-with-the-maven-failsafe-plugin), short answer is that maven-failsafe-plugin is not compatible with `Spring Boot 1.4`'s new executable layout. Full explanation below :

> As of `Failsafe 2.19`, `target/classes` is no longer on the classpath and
>   the project’s built jar is used instead. The plugin won’t be able to
>   find your classes due to the change in the executable jar layout.
>   There are two ways to work around this issue:
>
> - Downgrade to `2.18.1` so that you use target/classes instead
> - Configure the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to use a classifier for the
>     `repackage` goal. That way, the original jar will be available and used
>     by the plugin. For example :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pom12 - you saved my day. I've been debugging for like 8 hours now

Comment: You saved my day. thanks a lot

Comment: Adding <classifier>exec</classifier> to spring-boot-maven-plugin solved my issue. You saved my day. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

An alternative is documented here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <!--
        Make failsafe and spring-boot repackage play nice together,
        see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6254
    -->
    <configuration>
        <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This worked better for me, because when I used the "exec" solution, Spring failed to find my configuration files when starting the container. Which could probably be fixed by adding some further configuration parameters, I suppose, but this solution works "out of the box" for me.